# TScrollBar doesn't scroll to the end of panel

Tags: c++builder

I work with Borland C++ to develop my application.
I have a panel in which i will put dynamically items (labels for example).
In this panel, I add scrollBar.
My question is how to calculate PageSize (or other parameter) to let all item visible when scrolling ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the TScrollBox component. Just make it the parent of the components you want to create and dinamically position them into the ScrollBox determining its Top and Left position.

If you position a component (labels for example) inside it where the position exceeds the ScrollBox width or heigth the scrol bar will automatically be set appropriately for you.

Comment: the problem that i put in this panel a GLControl (which height doesn't change)

Comment: Which version of C++ Builder are you using? Are you using TPanel and TScrollBar to try to develop your application? Or what component(s) are you using to do it?

Comment: exactly, i am using C++ builder XE.
And for my application, i develop it using TPanel (containing a GLControl) with TScrollBar

Comment: sorry my question, but, what is a GLControl?

Comment: TGLControl is an OpenGl component, where i can draw (rectangles.. using openGL)

Comment: So, the components such as label you will add dinamicaly, will be added to the GLControl or to the Panel?

Comment: Anyway, if it's a component it can be resized. Just add the components you need to the TScrollBox, create components and resize them as much as you need and the TScrollBox will handle the scroll bars problem. That's it!

Comment: unfortunately, GlControl is not a resized component.